# Multiply numbers in array and add to an object in literal and dot notation

Tags: javascript

Just wondering how to do this code in literal and dot notation

```
function multi(num){
  var obj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
    obj[num[i]] = num[i] * 2;

  }
  return obj;  
}
```

If you use literal notation you cannot define the object like so `obj = {num[i] : num[i]*2}`
same goes for dot notation `obj.num[i] = num[i] * 2` will not work seeing as the key in literal and dot notation needs to be an actual string. Is there a way to define the key of an object as the current number and the value the current number multiplied by two of an object with literal or dot notation?

Comment: Nope, that's what the square brackets are for.

Comment: FWIW, `obj = {[num[i]] : num[i]*2}` notation is coming in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @blender so not doable in any other notation besides bracket?

Comment: @jharclerode: What's wrong with the bracket notation?

Comment: @blender its crimes against humanity. haha no dont mind bracket at all just was bored and for some reason I swear I did it before but was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so not doable in any other notation besides bracket? –  jharclerode

On a browser that supports `Object.defineProperty` (ECMA5) you also have this alternative, if you really must.

```
function multi(num) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, num[i], {
            value: num[i] * 2,
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
    return obj;
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log(multi(nums));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7wE6f/)